# Como fazer livereload em um servidor local?

Tags: gulp, gulpjs

Nos ultimos tempos vi muita informação sobre o Gulp.js para desenvolvimento front-end. E quero usar algumas funções dele como o livereload enquanto desenvolvo o front-end de uma aplicação em java.
Mas não encontro informações sobre fazer o gulp rodar junto com um outro servidor local externo que tenha comunicação com banco de dados.

Alguem sabe se é possivel, e qual a melhor maneira de fazer o gulp.js funcionar com aplicações assim?

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta mas voce pode usar o plugin Browser Sync para criar o servidor local que irá servir os arquivos do seu front-end com suporte a livereload.

**Para instalar:**

https://www.browsersync.io/

`npm install browser-sync --save`

**Configurando no Gulp:**

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});
```

Para rodar o gulp junto com sua aplicação, um caminho é configurar sua IDE, nas configurações do projeto acredito ser possível realizar um comando bash que irá inicializar o gulp e suas tarefas.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60582)

Comment: Obrigado! @rubStackOverflow inclui os trechos necessários. Sou iniciante aqui no Stack Overflow mas espero que agora tenha conseguido dar uma boa resposta.

Comment: @DanielBeff só uma dica, fica a seu critério seguir :) mas procure evitar usar formatação de titulo para topicos. O negrito já salienta bastante, com a fonte aumentada por toda a resposta, fica um pouco desagradável. Nessa resposta aqui, ficou ótimo, mas olhe essas por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120452/28595 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120447/28595 e essa também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120443/28595. Salientar em negrito ou usar formatação de titulo nessas respostas desses links tornou a resposta um pouco "alegórica" demais.

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoF vou melhorar a formatação !

Comment: Daniel, mas dai eu preciso usar o servidor que roda junto ao banco? Assim, estou desenvolvendo um sistema, ele usa tomcat como servidor no eclipse para rodar a aplicação e fazer a conexões com banco de dados. Mas eu queria fazer o livereload funcionar neste ambiente de desenvolvimento. Melhorou?

Comment: Você precisar usar o gulp em paralelo ao servidor do tomcat. Ele roda em um processo separado. Monitorando o que quando alterado você queira dar refresh na página. Baseado no exemplo que escrevi acima seria algo como você rodar sua aplicação no tomcat e no terminal rodar o comando `gulp browser-sync`. Não sei se ficou claro a explicação mas basicamente é isso. É lógico que precisa de mais configurações mas ai depende de como esta estruturado o projeto.