# Como usar os componentes do Bower usando o Gulp

Tags: gulp, bower

Eu uso o `Gulp` para me ajudar no desenvolvimento, até ai beleza se preciso do bootstrap ou jquery baixo coloco nas pastas que escolher e ok, mas gostaria de usar o `bower`, porem não entendi muito bem como que faço para usar os componentes que baixo via `bower` como `bootstrap`, `jquery`, etc...  ?

Tem algum jeito de fazer já compilar tudo junto com meus arquivos `scss` ou `js`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Usando o plugin gulp-useref**

Ele irá concatenar os arquivos que estiverem dentro de cada bloco comentado de build. Nesse link você poderá ver a documentação mais detalhada.

https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- build:css css/style.css -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- build:js scripts/bundle.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

No caso do SASS é preciso compilar primeiro o sass para então depois incluir o css gerado na página dentro do bloco de build. E assim gerar um arquivo com todos os css's desejados.

Esse plugin realiza essa tarefa:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass