# Compilar css com sass no Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, sass

Instalei o ruby no windows e instalei sass. Segundo o tutorial, eu tenho que monitorar o arquivo css, até então beleza, mas eu queria editar um arquivo css que já existe, e não um novo, como faço isso?

Comment: Salva ele em `.scss` e edita como Sass.

Comment: No caso, se tenho um arquivo minificado, eu tenho que pegar todos os css colar dentro do scss e dpois salvar ele como compressed?

Comment: Se o código estiver muito difícil de ler use esse site: http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Comment: Você pega o arquivo minificado e salva ele como `.scss` e modifica como quiser, ele vai salvar um `.css` de novo. Daí a maneira de usar os arquivos tanto faz tudo num só ou separado.

Comment: Você pode tentar esse app aqui: http://koala-app.com/

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Use Node.js para compilar arquivos sass para css.**

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

O Node.js é bem mais rápido para compilar que o ruby e a esmagadora maioria das ferramentas para front-end rodam nele atualmente. Inclusive o SASS usando node-sass.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Para instalar (com o node.js previamente instalado) execute o comando no terminal:

`npm install -g node-sass`

E para compilar um arquivo sass para css execute o comando no terminal:

`node-sass style.scss style.css`

**2 - Você precisa monitorar os arquivos `.scss` e não os arquivos `.css`**

Os arquivos `.scss` dão origem ao `.css` e não o contrário. Então você precisa alterar a extensão do arquivo `.css` que você deseja alterar para a extensão `.scss`.