# Como usar o bower para instalar de um repositório do bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bower

Aqui na empresa onde trabalho, temos algumas bibliotecas que desenvolvemos especificamente para a empresa. Por isso eu estou usando o bitbucket, com um repositório privado.

Como posso fazer para instalar via `bower`, uma biblioteca `javascript` ou `css`, que está num repositório bitbucket privado? Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070745/how-to-use-bower-with-private-bitbucket-repository

Comment: Ingrês, pris, transleite

Answer (score 3):

**Instale usando a URL do repositório.**

Exemplo:

`bower install git@bitbucket.org:user/biblioteca.git --save`

Utilize `--save` caso deseje que o bower já inclua essa dependência no seu arquivo de configuração do bower.